# cannot target dynamic id with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on a script that logins a website and does some button clicks. Although its not that hard, I have done this for other websites but this website seem to have dynamic id's which is making it hard for me to locate the fields. When ever I refresh the page, the id changes but it does have some text that does not change. I searched stackoverflow and found some code that I tried but didnt work. The code does nothing and the browser just closes. I have tried chrome and firefox both do the same thing. I am really new to python selenium plz help.
this is the page

```
https://www.quora.com/

driver.find_element_by_name("email")
```

> driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "email")]').send_keys('ssss')

```
<input class="text header_login_text_box ignore_interaction" name="email" tabindex="1" data-group="js-editable" placeholder="Email" w2cid="IDHg1fF" id="__w2_IDHg1fF_email" type="text">
<input class="text header_login_text_box ignore_interaction" name="password" tabindex="2" data-group="js-editable" placeholder="Password" w2cid="IDHg1fF" id="__w2_IDHg1fF_password" type="password">
```

how can i target these two fields ? as they do have a text that is at the end of the id. but the number keeps changing.

Comment: Try using the name identifier: `driver.find_element_by_name("email")`

Comment: Yes i already used it but the browser closes. and does not input any fields

Comment: Can you share page URL?

Comment: yes https://www.quora.com/

Comment: no one has a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there are two elements that match your locator and the first one is not visible. There are a couple ways to handle this.

1. Use the 2nd one

   ```
   driver.find_elements_by_name("email")[1].send_keys()
   ```
2. Get the full list of elements that matches the locator and filter the list to only the visible one

   ```
   emails = driver.find_elements_by_name("email")
   email = next(element for element in emails if element.is_displayed())
   email.send_keys()
   ```

The second one is probably the better approach... less fragile.

A tip... a quick way to avoid this issue is to test your locators in the browser. Open your page in Chrome and open the dev toolbar. To test CSS selectors use `$$()`, e.g. `$$("input[name='email']")`. To test XPaths, use `$x()`, e.g. `$x("//input[@name='email']")`. When you enter these, it will return the number of elements that match that locator. If there are more than one, expand the collection and hover each one until the one you are looking for lights up on the page. That will tell you if any and which one is the one you are looking for. You can then decide whether to use that locator or try another one. This will help you identify the right locator before you ever leave the page instead of putting it in code, running it only to find it failed, and then trying another one. It cuts down the time between iterations significantly.

Answer (score -1):

That's not a very stable method, but it works well now.

```
#Find all input elements    
inp=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('input')
#Sending keys to Email field
inp[5].send_keys('Your login name')
#Sending keys to Password field
inp[6].send_keys('Password')
#Click on login button
inp[7].click()
```

Comment: wow.. that really worked. it doesnt clicks the button but fills the form... although you just inserted into a variable .. i would like to know what does input[4] means ?? how can i target more fields this way ? can you explain.. this python is strange

Comment: That's not a good approach because if the form changes, your script will break. Avoid using indices to find elements.